# Change ActionBar Menu Item icon on click

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want my action bar menu item icon to change from `ic_action_mic` to `ic_action_micoff` and vice versa on click. My code works but not always.

```
 @Override
    protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu) {
       if(tempItem!=null && tts!=null) {
           if (tts.isSpeaking())
               tempItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_micoff));
           else
               tempItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_mic));
       }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
    }

    TextToSpeech tts;
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        if (id == R.id.action_read)
        {

            if(tts != null)
                if(tts.isSpeaking())
                {
                    tts.stop();
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    return true;
                }

            //read the whole news
            tts = new TextToSpeech(newsActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();

                    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
                    {
                        TextView txtNews = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewNewsDescription);
                        String readableText = txtNews.getText().toString();
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                        tts.setSpeechRate(.85f);
                        //tts.speak("Hi!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        tts.speak(readableText ,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Kindly suggest me how can I achieve what I want. TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "my code works but not always"?

Comment: Well it does not work the way I want it to. Sometimes the icons swap and sometimes they don't.

Comment: When does it work?  And when does it not?

Comment: It always starts speaking when I click it and stops speaking when I click it again. This is perfect so far. But I also want the icon to change when it is speaking and change back when it is done speaking or stopped, which is not happening.

Comment: Why not just change the value of tempItem icon in onOptionItemSelected()?

Comment: That was the most obvious solution. But unfortunately that didn't work. I read somewhere that we need to `invalidate` the Action Bar so that it draws again, thus makes a call to `onPrepareOptionsPanel`.